# How to find identical bitposition in a string?

Tags: python-3.x, bitstring

I have created a sequence of bitstring. Now I want to calculate the identical bit positions all sequences one by one.
I don't understand how to find it.

```
S1: 00010101110011100010000110000111010100101010101110101011001111100010110101110001001010010111010110000111110110100100100111000100
    for round in range(0, 5):
    rawvalues_sim_str = "".join(rawvalues_sim)
    startindex=0
    endindex=128
    for i in range(0, len(rawvalues_sim_str),128):
        b=rawvalues_sim_str[startindex:endindex]
        startindex = endindex
        endindex += 128
        #Find sequence in bitstring 
        if b[round] == round:
            d = b[round]
            print(d)
    print(b)
```

Comment: Why did you tag this with `quantum-computing`, `qiskit`, `ibm-mq`? I don't see the connection.

Comment: Something to do with [**Bitwise AND**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND). But I am not entirely sure what you have as input, and expect as output `{in: [01110, 10111, 11110], out: 00110}` or `out: indices [2, 3]`

Comment: NO actually, The string S1 is what I got as output. Now its save in the memory. Now I want to calculate the position of 0 and 1 in string S1